# Unit testing with external files

Tags: java, unit-tests

I started writing unit tests recently and need to test reading fields in a spreadsheet (.xlsx and .xls), my biggest question is: 
Should I create a spreadsheet by code using Apache POI or use external spreadsheet models that are used in software? **What is the best practice?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How the spreadsheet/workbook is created shouldn't matter. You may have some issues with cells whose value is derived from a formula though. I like to work with .csv files if at all possible. They are much easier to parse if you write the java code yourself (without using 3rd party libraries).

Here are a few examples for Excel file types, from HelloSelenium.com, that I found:

1. [HOW TO PERFORM DATA DRIVEN USING EXCEL FILE (.XLSX) IN SELENIUM WEBDRIVER ?](http://www.helloselenium.com/2014/09/how-to-perform-data-driven-using-excel.html)
2. [HOW TO READ DATA FROM EXCEL FILE (.XLSX) USING APACHE POI?](http://www.helloselenium.com/2014/09/how-to-read-data-from-excel-file-xlsx.html)

Comment: My question is time to take the test. The code that will test already uses Apache POI. When testing, ride a Java spreadsheet or make test with an existing spreadsheet (External file)?

Comment: I would call the file if it is static. In some of my tests that require a file for a FileDialog, I first check to see if the file exists on the file system and if not I generate a new one or copy it to the local file system from some other end-point.